# How to use page object variable on protractor .each() function?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor, pageobjects

I was wondering how to use page object variable on `.each()` function.

The scenario is every I click delete link, the sweet alert confirmation will be shown, and I must confirm that dialog to delete the data.

Here is my page object:

```
'use strict';

// page object name
var Data = function()
{
    // all delete links
    this.delete_links = element.all(by.css('div[ng-click="delete(Data.id)"]'));

    // confirm button
    this.btn_confirm = element(by.css('.confirm'));

    // delete function
    this.delete = function()
    {
        // delete all links with confirmation
        this.delete_links.each(function(element, index)
        {
            // click delete link
            element.click().then(function()
            {
                browser.sleep(1000);
            });

            // click yes
            this.btn_confirm.click().then(function()
            {
                browser.sleep(1000);
            });
        });
    };
};

module.exports = Data;
```

Comment: But what you are experiencing difficulties with? Does the `delete` function do what you expect it to do? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe No, it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'btn_confirm' of undefined" Sir.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the "each" function/callback does not refer to the page object itself. To fix it, define a variable and set it to `this.btn_confirm`:

```
this.delete = function()
{
    // delete all links with confirmation
    this.delete_links.each(function(element, index)
    {
        var confirmButton = this.btn_confirm;

        // click delete link
        element.click().then(function()
        {
            browser.sleep(1000);
        });

        // click yes
        confirmButton.click().then(function()
        {
            browser.sleep(1000);
        });
    });
};
```